# Redirect from port 80 to 2222 and change the URL on a subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to remove the port number on the end of my url, additionally I am also trying to map it to a different url also.

For example I have the url

```
subdomain.example.com
```

the url I currently visit to see the directory is

```
subdomain.example.com:2222/path/path/
```

I am using Apache and have subdomain.example.com in the /sites-available folder.  I also have .htaccess in the directory defined in the vhosts for that.

I have tried to redirect like so (in the subdomains .htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^path/path/(.*) http://subdomain.example.com:2222/$1 [P,L]
```

But it doesnt seem to even redirect

Also ive tried to set the vhosts

```
<VirtualHost *:2222>
[my setting in here]
</VirtualHost>
```

reloading apache , a2ensite etc.  But nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: Did you enable `mod_proxy` in your Apache config?

Comment: Yes I have it enabled.  Just displays whats in that directory instead of proxy to port :2222/path/path.

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: consider reposting to http://serverfault.com/